# a guide for WPF Networking

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a small WPF Project. The data is being stored on Server machine. I want, that the clients can access that database by a WPF Software. The connection is only LAN. Any idea, how to develop my WPF APP further? Perhaps WCF? any book or any quelle that can help me specific with this topic?

thanks guys!

Comment: WPF has nothing to do with networking: it's a UI framework. WCF is obsolete and dead (hurrah!). If it's just a database system then use `SqlConnection`/`OleDbConnection`/`OdbcConnection` as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your application will be used.

From a WPF application you can connect directly to your database and it is the easiest way but, not allways the best.

If your application will be used only on internal network, you can use SQL Connection, an ORM like Entity Framework etc.

But, if you want to use your application externally, I mean for exemple at home, you will need to open the TCP/IP Port on your Database Server in order to be able to connect from your application using SQLConnection. This is not difficult but will make your server vulnerable against hacker attacks. In this case, you can use a web service to publish on your server and consume it in order to communicate with your db. The disadvantage of this is the development time. Ofcourse developing a web service and consuming it will take more time to develop than connecting directly via an SQLConnection.

For me, you must choose the most optimised for your case.

Comment: hey dude, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Comment: if you don't mind, I've my last question before posting a second question here! the question is: a WPF Project with SQL Server database connection, after publishing this WPF project, are the WPF and SQL Server database packed together?

Comment: No problem! Sql Server database independent from wpf project. You can use localdb to have a db file in your project but if we are talking about an SQL Server database, it will be separated.  Are you working on an existing database or you will create one ?

Comment: thanks for your patience, I am working on one new one! which is for my shop (an accounting software), therefore I am not professional, but thanks for such helpful guys like you on this platform!
You mentioned local database, which are those?
If I create my Database on SQLite by SQLite Manager, can I connect that with my WPF Project (like MSQL Server)?
If yes, if I publish the WPF App, are the DB and WPF App together or still separate?

Comment: Don't worry, that is the objective of the stackoverflow :) So, for your application, if you want to use SQL Server, you should download and install SQL Server Express edition which is free but limited to 10 Gb and source using level. But, for your application it will be sufficent. Here is the link to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads. And you need SQL Server Management Studio or another tool to manage your databases. You can install your sql server on the pc wher you will install your wpf application. Or you can install it on another pc or server.

Comment: In this case, you will change your connection string and put the IP of your db server. You don't need to keep the database and your aplication on the same PC but if you want, you can do it. If you use sqlite, it will be a simple db file. You can put it on the same folder of your application. You don't need to instal a Database system like SQL Server on any post. You can connect easily to sqllite database from your wpf application. Here is a tutorial : http://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/

Comment: ohhh wow dude, you've shown my direction. thanks a lot! I've already started the SQLite with DataGrip. After finishing the SQLite, should I drag and drop the SQLite into the WPF Solution, am I right?? rest is ado.net, I guess!

Comment: Happy for you :) You're welcome. In fact, sqlite database is a simple file. You can put it into your solution or another folder. You should precise the full path of this file in your connection string. The rest is ADO.NET or Entity framework as you said. Here a tutorial to show how to connect to sqlite database : http://zetcode.com/csharp/sqlite/ .

Comment: I got them all, really many thanks for your patience. I wish, I could keep contact longer to get profit of your knowledge in future problems. but this platform doesn't let to have a user as a friend.

Comment: No problem, I will answer your questions as long as I can. Don't hesitate to post another question on StackOverFlow.